# I have labeled regions, but, where are they on the image?

Tags: matlab, label, region

I have used the property `Area` in `regionprops()` in order to find the area of every labeled region in a labeled image.

The question here is, for instance, say that I now have `300` labeled regions. I now know the area of each labeled region. But, how can I know which region in the image each label represents. Say that I have a region with label "176". How can I know what part of the image represents this label?

Thanks.

Comment: are you going to ask a question about every single line of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the labeled regions for this. For example

```
L = bwlabel( BW ); % L is your labled image
rg = regionprops( L, 'Area' ); % you use L for regionprops
figure; imagesc( L == 176 );axis image; title('showing region 176');
```